# Why am I not receiving output for this while loop in python?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to python and trying to learn through small projects:

I am trying to write a code where if suppose you are in a large-lecture class with n other students.Determine how large n must be such that the probability that someone has the same birthday as you is greater than 50%?
Note: Forgetting about leap years
and so assuming 365 days in a year, the probability that no one has the same birthday as you is (364/365)**n

My code for this is:

```
n=probability
probability = 0
while n==0.50*n:
    print("With n students, the
probability
is greater than
50% that someone has the same
birthday
as you.")
```

Where am I going wrong?How could I implement an ifstatement?The output I am looking for is:

> With 253 students, the probability is greater than 50% that someone
>   has the same birthday as you.

Comment: 1. Floats are almost never exactly equal to other floats, using `==` almost never succeeds. 2. Which `n` is exactly equal to `n*0.5`…?

Comment: Where does `n` change?

Comment: I would suggest writing an *algorithm* in plain old English before trying to code.

Comment: No value is never equal to half of itself.

Comment: ... well, I guess zero and infinity are.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to fix your code without redoing it entirely, so here we go:

```
p = 1/365
n = 0

# Search for the number of students that ensures p(same birthday)>50%.
while 1-(1-p)**n < 0.50 :
    n = n+1

print("With {number} students, the probability is greater than 50% that someone has the same birthday as you.".format(number=n))
```

Feel free to ask extra information.

Comment: thank you this works. But can u please shed light of the {number} dictionary u wrote under print? Im not very familiar with it. How was it able to detect 253

Comment: At the end of the `while` loop we have n=253. Now you can format strings in several ways. Using .format in `"With {number} students".format(number=n)` we tell the string to replace the variable between brackets by n. Alternatively you could do `"With %d students" %n` if you prefer. Here is an useful link for formatting strings: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 0):

this is not returning an output because the condition of n==0.5*n is false, so the loop never runs to begin with.

Comment: This script will raise a NameError anyway at the first line `n = probability`.